# Why does $\mathcal{B}=\cup_{n\in{}\mathcal{Z}_+}\mathcal{B}_n$ mean the basis is countable?

Tags: general-topology

In the first page of chapter 6 in Munkres it is asserted that one way of expressing the condition that the basis of a topology $\mathcal{B}$ is countable is to say that $\mathcal{B}$ can be expressed in the form

$$\mathcal{B}=\cup_{n\in{}\mathcal{Z}_+}\mathcal{B}_n$$

where $\mathcal{Z}_n$ is the set of the positive integers and each collection $\mathcal{B}_n$ is finite. Why is this equivalent with $\mathcal{B}$ being countable?

Comment: Because the union of countably many countable sets is countable, and finite sets are countable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so why bother asking the $\mathcal{B}_n$ to be finite? why not just countable?

Comment: Because Munkres is trying to use this idea to explain why one might look at $\sigma$-locally finite bases. He wants to generalize from *finite* to *locally finite*. The generalization from *countable* to *locally countable* doesn’t work, so he’s forced to stick with *finite*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thanks

Comment: My pleasure; glad to help.